# Compilation error in certain pattern of java's switch-yield syntax

Tags: java, switch-statement

An unknown syntax error occurs due to the Logical not sign while writing Java's switch-yield statement.
After the yield as below '!' will cause a compilation error.

```
final var error = switch(args[0]) {
    case "A" -> {
        yield !true || true;
    }
    default -> false;
};
```

The compile error message printed out is:

```
error: not a statement
                yield !true || true;
                ^
```

As follows '!' After writing the code, it compiles successfully.

```
final var success = switch(args[0]) {
    case "A" -> {
        yield true || !true;
    }
    default -> false;
};
```

Comment: funny: `yield (!true) || true;` works

Comment: Both codes work in my environment (JDK19).

Comment: java 16 gives `not a statement` error

Comment: Occurs when tested on JDK 15 version.
This was a bug and seems to have been fixed, as testing with JDK 17 and higher did not produce any compilation errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a JDK bug.

See [[JDK-8268670] yield statements doesn't allow ~ or ! unary operators in expression - Java Bug System](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8268670)

It seems to be resolved in version 17.

Comment: Tried and no error in openjdk 17.0.2